# Ant build.xml causes java.io.IOException: System cannot find the specified file

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, ant

I am getting the following error message when I try to run the following build.xml file to work with mysql from my java application in eclipse:

BUILD FAILED
d:\mypath\workspace\appname\database\build.xml:14: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Here is the code for build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="publisher" default="all" basedir=".">
  <property name="mysql.params" value="-u publisher -ppublisher -D publisher" />
  <target name="all" depends="cleandb, createdb, insertdb"></target>

  <target name="cleandb">
     <exec executable="mysql" input="cleandb.sql">
        <arg line="${mysql.params}" />
     </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="createdb">
     <exec executable="mysql" input="createdb.sql">
        <arg line="${mysql.params}" />
     </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="insertdb">
     <exec executable="mysql" input="insertdb.sql">
        <arg line="${mysql.params}" />
     </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

From eclipse, I am running the file as "Ant Build..." and am calling createdb.sql first.  Thus, the line that is throwing is the first line that is being asked to execute, which is:

The problem seems to be that the script is not able to locate mysql.  From the windows command line, I am able to call the instance of the database using the following path:
    d:\mypath\MySQL\MySQL Server\bin\mysqld

I think the xml file needs to specify the path of the mysql installation, but I am not sure how to do that while also passing the parameters required in the code above.  This is my first time working with Ant and with mysql, so the syntax is new to me.

Can anyone show me how to fix the code above so that it can find my database?

***EDIT:***

---

I followed whiskeyspider's suggestion and edited my code to become the following:

```
-- I had a bunch of code here that I am now omitting for brevity because  
-- there is a newer, revised version of the code in the second edit below.
```

It may help some readers to know that I am trying to use code from [this tutorial](http://cse.csusb.edu/turner/java_web_programming/mysql/).  The difference is that I am using version 5.6 of mysql and Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800 of Eclipse.  The tutorial uses older versions of both applications, which is what is causing the confusion.

***SECOND EDIT:***

---

I changed the build.xml file again to implement whiskeyspider's second round of corrections.  The script now accesses the mysql database, but there is another message about which I have a question, below.

Here is the new build.xml code, which runs correctly now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="publisher" default="all" basedir=".">
  <property name="mysql.params" value="-u publisher -ppublisher -D publisher" />
  <property name="mysql.exec.path" value="d:\\mypath\\MySQL\\bin\\"/>
  <target name="all" depends="cleandb, createdb, insertdb"></target>

  <target name="cleandb">
     <exec executable="${mysql.exec.path}/mysqld" input="cleandb.sql">
        <arg line="${mysql.params}" />
     </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="createdb">
     <exec executable="${mysql.exec.path}/mysqld" input="createdb.sql">
        <arg line="${mysql.params}" />
     </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="insertdb">
     <exec executable="${mysql.exec.path}/mysqld" input="insertdb.sql">
        <arg line="${mysql.params}" />
     </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

Here is the log reported in the eclipse console when build.xml is run:

```
Buildfile: d:\mypath\workspace\publisher\database\build.xml
createdb:
     [exec] Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
insertdb:
     [exec] Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Can anyone tell me how I can address this warning by improving security when I need to use passwords to get into databases from ant code run using eclipse?  How, specifically, can I change my code so that the same tasks are performed without the security risk?

Comment: I think the original problem is solved. You should accept the answer. The issue here is that you are fighting an program which is external to ANT. An alternative approach is to consider a pure Java solution using the sql task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property with the path to the executable:

```
<property name="mysql.exec.path" value="C:/path/to/it" />
```

You can make it portable by first loading a local properties file that may override it, for example:

```
<property file="${user.home}/local.properties" />  // can override mysql.exec.path property, if necessary
<property name="mysql.exec.path" value="C:/path/to/it" />  // if not, use the default
```

Then reference it like so:

```
<exec executable="${mysql.exec.path}/mysql" input="cleandb.sql">
  <arg line="${mysql.params}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your code but then got another problem.  I have described it along with revised code in an edit to my original posting above.  Can you make further suggestions? +1 for trying to help.

Comment: @CodeMed In your revised code above, use forward slashes (/) when defining the mysql.exec.path property.  Since you are using backslashes, you are escaping the double-quote, which is what is causing the problem.  You are also missing the forward slash to end the tag.  Here is what you need: `<property name="mysql.exec.path" value="d:/mypath/MySQL/bin/" />`

Comment: @CodeMed  And if for some reason the forward slashes in the path cause an issue, use double backslashes instead.

Comment: Thank you again. +1 a second time for continuing to help.  The revised script above now runs, thanks to your help, but it is throwing a security risk alert shown above in a second edit to my original posting.  Can you tell me how to address the security concern being raised by the alert?

Comment: @CodeMed The warning is coming from MySQL, not Ant.  Might be worthy of a new post.  This (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html) might help.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve your goal is to add `.../mysql/bin` folder to your `PATH`.

If it's not an option, you can specify mysql location via property: `-Dmysql.bin.dir=/path/to/mysql` and then use `<exec executable="${mysql.bin.dir}/mysql" input="cleandb.sql">`

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know how to do that.  Can you show me the altered version of the specific line(s) of code that you suggest changing in order to accomplish what you propose?

Comment: First option is platform-specific. Google for `set PATH in ${your.os.name}`. After you change the PATH, run ant from new console and everything should work fine.

The second option is straightforward: I've already provided you the line you need to change. And you should run ant as follow: `ant -Dmysql.bin.dir=/path/to/your/mysql/installation`. That's all.

Comment: Thank you again.  I did google setting the path, and I revised the code in my original posting above to change the path.  Now I am getting another problem, described above.  I suspect from your comments that you are not using eclipse.  I am trying to learn how to do this in eclipse.  If i did it your way, at what point in the build.xml file above would I insert -Dmysql.bin.dir=/path/to/mysql ?  +1 for trying to help.

Comment: Actualy, I am eclipse user :) But I prefer to run ant/maven from console. In your case you need to create custom ant run configuration and specify parameter to it: http://clip2net.com/s/2NOv0. This is `Run`->`Run configurations` menu.

Comment: Thank you again.  I have now inserted     -Dmysql.bin.dir=/path/to/mysql into the arguments section within Run -> Run Configurations, and I have changed each executable line in build.xml to <exec executable="${mysql.bin.dir}/mysql" input="cleandb.sql">.  But it is now throwing the same error message that it threw when I first made this posting, described above.  I checked to make sure the exact path is correct.  I also tried <exec executable="${mysql.bin.dir}/mysqld" input="cleandb.sql"> because the executable file is named mysqld.  Any more suggestions?